# remove last element of list within a Series

Tags: pandas, immutability, series, nested-lists, del

I've tried different variations of pop, remove, and del with no success thus far. I'm not finding any documentation that addresses this particular issue. Thanks in advance

```
listoflists = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['e','f','g','h']]

series1 = pd.Series(listoflists)
```

->

```
0      [a, b, c, d]
1      [e, f, g, h]
dtype: object
```

I want to remove the last element of each list within the series to get:

```
0      [a, b, c]
1      [e, f, g]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.apply()` with lambda:

```
series1.apply(lambda x: x[:-1])
```

From each list we take all elements except of the last one.

**Output:**

```
0    [a, b, c]
1    [e, f, g]
```

Comment: You could also use the built-in `series1.str[:-1]`.